# Convert curl --form to C#

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I'm working with an external api and want to upload file using multipart/form-data. The working solution in curl is: `curl --form file=@./fileName.mp4 "http://page.com"`

According to https://curl.olsh.me/. The code I'm looking for is:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "http://page.com/"))
        {
            var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            multipartContent.Add(new  ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes("./fileName.mp4")), "file", Path.GetFileName("./fileName.mp4"));
        request.Content = multipartContent; 

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    }
}
```

However it doesn't work. The headers and the file is different so I'm getting an error.

The code I've written and 'works', but the attachment is not valid, because encoding bytes to string is incorrect.

```
var webClient = new HttpClient();
            webClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = true;
            string boundary = "------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
            var fileData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pathToFile));
            var package = string.Format("--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n{3}\r\n--{0}--\r\n", boundary, "fileName", "application/octet-stream", fileData);
            var content = new StringContent(package);
            content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
            content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
            content.Headers.Remove("Content-Length");
            content.Headers.Add("Content-Length", package.Length.ToString());
await webClient.PostAsync(address, content);
```

Edit:
The headers from curl request:

```
POST http://page.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: page.com
User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
Accept: */*
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 1703578
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------1a538744c5619c1e

--------------------------1a538744c5619c1e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="cst.mp4"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

The headers from the 1st example code:

```
POST http://page.com/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="735b20d4-4de4-46fb-8293-2c2e996ce180"
Content-Length: 1703552
Host: page.com

--735b20d4-4de4-46fb-8293-2c2e996ce180
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=file; filename=cst.mp4; filename*=utf-8''cst.mp4
```

Comment: When the first code example doesn't work, what error do you receive specifically? It is definitely the better / preferred way.

Comment: Forbidden - however I just want to receive exactly the same request as using the curl. So the errors I'm receiving in the middle should not be important.

Comment: Start with the first example. Use `request.ToString()` to dump the request content and see what differs. Once you know what differs, we can debug / fix.

Comment: I have updated my question. I'm not able to fix the file headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the first code is that the boundary, file headers and output headers differs. I had to add two Content-Type headers - one to my file and one to the output. I was unable to add the correct headers and remove the wrong one, beacuse I tried to add headers to multipart instead of multipart content.
If you want to add headers to your multipart content you need to do it on `HttpContent`.
The working solution is:

```
string boundary = "------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), address))
                {
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", userAgentName);
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = true;
                    var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent(boundary);
                    multipartContent.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
                    multipartContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary);
                    var bcd = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path));
                    bcd.Headers.Clear();
                    bcd.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\""+fileName+"\"");
                    bcd.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
                    multipartContent.Add(bcd, "file", fileName);
                    request.Content = multipartContent;

                    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                }
            }
```

Now the headers from curl and the HttpClient are almost the same(Accept header is missing, but I don't need it).

Answer (score 0):

I think the file size difference is a red herring here.

A common practice for web servers is to deny requests that don't specify a user agent. Try adding a user agent (or even spoofing the curl agent) as below:

```
webClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "curl/7.55.1");
```

Comment: I'm still getting Forbidden. I'm pretty sure that it's because the file is not valid. Look at the headers and boundary.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the User-Agent is being added to the headers in the output?

Comment: Yes. Moreover adding the other headers doesn't help. The file is incorrect same as the boundary. I need to add correct Content-Type and Content-Disposition to the file header, but I don't know how.